# Will apps made using Xcode 6 compatible with iOS9?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9

I have developed an app using Xcode 6, it runs well till iOS8, but I want it to run on iOS9 too. So, will it work if I submit the the app onto the Appstore right away, or should I download Xcode 7 and rebuild it..and then upload it to the app store..? What should I do..? Please help me out..! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test your iOS 8 app on a device with iOS 9? Does it work as expected or are there issues? If it works, you are fine. It it doesn't, you need to fix it.

Comment: There's no reason not to download Xcode 7, and at least run your app on the iOS 9 simulator.

Comment: Here is what I have found with iOS releases. In theory your app should work when a new ios is released. You do however need to get the latest framework and thoroughly test on a device if possible, or at least the simulator. In one case 2 of my apps that used the old UIPickerView stopped working completely because they changed that.

Comment: You should always upgrade to Xcode 7 to support iOS9, it can support iOS8 too, but Xcode 6 can max support iOS8.

Comment: I tested my app with an iOS9 device using Xcode 6.0.1 ..it didn't work...I got a dialogue box saying.."Unable to mount on this version of OS"..something like that. So do you think will my app work in iOS9 ..if I uploaded it to the Appstore using Xcode 6.0.1. I mean most of the people have upgraded to iOS9..so what do you think..will it work in practical..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps built with Xcode 6 will still work fine with iOS 9, as long as you haven't done anything in your code that won't work in 9.  Compiling the binary with na older version of XCode will rarely cause any problems, but there certainly are things you can do in your code that work fin on iOS 8 that will not work correctly in iOS 9.

You should definitely test the app on iOS 9.  This can be more challenging with Xcode 6, since you cannot build straight to an iOS9 device from Xcode 6.  I would upgrade to the latest version of Xcode (7) and run your app on the device.  If there are critical, show-stopper issues, I would troubleshoot and fix the issues and push an update to the App Store using the xepedited review process Apple allows.  For justification, simply put that there are critical issues with iOS 9.  If you don't find any issues, or if the issues are minor, I would wait until your next scheduled release to build with Xcode 7.

Comment: Xcode 6 can certainly be used to build and debug on an iOS 9 device. But for that work you must connect the device with Xcode 7 once.

Comment: Yes, but at that point, they would have installed Xcode 7.  If he's just trying to check for issues, Simpy running from Xcode 7 would be easiest. You could also build with a distribution profile to an ipa and install with a recent version of iTunes.  The key is that compiling a binary in Xcode 6 and submitting to Apple will not cause problems with the app on iOS9.   Also, unless they are doing something crazy, the upgrade to Xcode 7 is relatively painless, so if they're not already in the app store, why not just upgrade and take advantage of the improvements in Xcode 7.

Comment: But the OP has a working app built with Xcode 6 and some unknown language. Running the app in Xcode 7 will require Swift 2 instead of Swift 1.2 (if relevant). It will use a different Base SDK so things may work differently. The OP will go from a working, known app, to an app that may require lots and lots of code changes just to compile and will require complete retesting on all supported iOS versions, in addition to iOS 9. Sticking with Xcode 6 (for now) requires only testing iOS 9. Yes, upgrading must be done at some point, but now may be too soon for the OP.

Comment: Agreed.  As I said, if it's a simple app it will require little work in Xcode 7 to get it running (as was the case for all of our 10 apps).  If you feel that installing Xcode 7 simply for the purpose of prepping it for use with Xcode 6, the great thing about SO is that you can add that answer.  At this point, I think that would be better than trying to hash out our opinions in this comment thread.

Comment: can you name some of "things you can do in your code that work fin on iOS 8 that will not work correctly in iOS 9." please?

Comment: I don't have any specifics, but our app had some minor issues in iOS 9 that we fixed.  Nothing major - a few layout issues, maybe one crash. You'd have to troubleshoot. But with iOS 9 out for 6 months, you shouldknow by know if your app has iOS9 issues.